# url length decrease from htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

This is what I am going to do:

If user search

https://englishact.com/Quotation/Every+man+must+do+two+things+alone.html

htaccess will display (only five character)

https://englishact.com/Quotations/allquot.php?quotation=Every

I am trying it in htaccess but not working:

```
RewriteRule    ^Quotation/([.]{5})(.*)\.html$    Quotations/allquot.php?quotation=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

Will be helpful if you can give me edit in the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue in your RegEx. `[.]` will match exactly a `.` instead if any character since the `.` is wrapped in `[]`.

Try the below rule. It should work.

```
RewriteRule    ^Quotation/(.{5})(.*)\.html$    Quotations/allquot.php?quotation=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

Comment: You can visit https://englishact.com/Quotation/young+and+vital+child+knows+no+limit+to+his+n+will.html

Comment: Two urls have different content

Comment: In your first url there is an error. `Notice: Undefined variable: quot in /home/englishact/public_html/Quotations/allquot.php on line 228`. This means the contents are being served from the `allquot.php` file. Which means the rewrite rule worked.

Answer (score 1):

To capture only the first five letters after `Quotation/` and before the `+` sign you can try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?quotation/([a-z0-9.]{5}).*\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /quotations/allquot.php?quotation=%1 [NC,L]
```

it will accept the first five characters of the query string if they are characters between a-z (case insensitive because of NC flag),numbers 0-9 or a period.

Comment: Above code is already accepting. You can visit from the live url. But I want to decrease the length of url.

Comment: @AsifIqbal decrease or increase the number of characters and to how many?

Comment: I want to accept only 5 character url (containing + a-z 0 -9 and .)